# JS - reaching to the element is not accurate

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a css class when user reaches an element.

```js
var pag_offset = $('.pagination_extra').offset();
$('.pagination-wrapper').addClass('pagination-wrapper-fixed');
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(window).height() + pag_offset.top - 100) {
     $('.pagination-wrapper').addClass('pagination-wrapper-fixed');
   } else {
     $('.pagination-wrapper').removeClass('pagination-wrapper-fixed');
   }
});
```

```css
.pagination_extra {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.pagination-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pagination-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin:auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.pagination-wrapper-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 7;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .pagination {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
}

.page-numbers {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  float: left;
  transition: 300ms ease;
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-family: nazanin;
}
.page-numbers:hover, .page-numbers.current {
  background-color: #86c023;
  color: #fff;
}
.page-numbers.prev:hover, .page-numbers.next:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #86c023;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .page-numbers {
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 120px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .page-numbers {
    padding: 0 14px;
    display: none;
  }
  .page-numbers:nth-of-type(2) {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
  .page-numbers:nth-of-type(2)::after {
    content: "...";
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 25px;
    top: 0;
    left: 45px;
  }
  .page-numbers:nth-child(-n + 3), .page-numbers:nth-last-child(-n + 3) {
    display: block;
  }
  .page-numbers:nth-last-child(-n + 4) {
    padding-right: 14px;
  }
  .page-numbers:nth-last-child(-n + 4)::after {
    content: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination_extra"></div>
<div class="pagination-wrapper">
  <div class="pagination">
    <a class="prev page-numbers">&larr;</a>
    <a class="page-numbers">1</a>
    <a class="page-numbers">2</a>
    <a class="page-numbers">3</a>
    <a class="page-numbers">4</a>
    <a class="next page-numbers">&rarr;</a>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1><h1>foo<br></h1>
```

When user reaches the `.pagination_extra` element it should add a CSS class.

The problem is that it's not accurate when it hasn't reached the element it will remove the class.

So I tried to add or subtract the offset value like `pag_offset.top - 100` but it will change on different screen size.

How can I make it accurate that when user exactly reaches the `.pagination_extra` element it changes the class?

Comment: What do you mean by "reaches"? You're using the scroll event, so I think you mean scrolling, but do you want to add the class when the element appears at the *bottom* of the viewport, or when it reaches the middle, or the top?

Comment: It looks to me like your code makes sure the element has the class until the `.pagination_extra` element reaches the top of the viewport, then it ensures it doesn't have the class. That works in your example when I remove the `- 100`. What are you seeing that makes you think it isn't working? You did say you wanted to do the opposite (add the class when the element is reached, remove it when it isn't), is that the problem? (But you probably know you could just reverse the logic, so...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do what you are trying to achieve using only CSS with [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky):

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.pagination-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination-wrapper {
  position: sticky;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: calc(100vh - 58px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.page-numbers {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  transition: 300ms ease;
  color: #595959;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.page-numbers:hover, .page-numbers.current {
  background-color: #86c023;
  color: #fff;
}

.page-numbers.prev:hover, .page-numbers.next:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #86c023;
}

.page-numbers {
  padding: 0 14px;
  display: none;
}

.page-numbers:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.page-numbers:nth-of-type(2)::after {
  content: "…";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
  top: 0;
  left: 45px;
}

.page-numbers:nth-child(-n + 3), .page-numbers:nth-last-child(-n + 3) {
  display: block;
}

.page-numbers:nth-last-child(-n + 4) {
  padding-right: 14px;
}

.page-numbers:nth-last-child(-n + 4)::after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>

<div class="pagination_extra"></div>

<div class="pagination-wrapper">
  <div class="pagination">
    <a class="prev page-numbers">&larr;</a>
    <a class="page-numbers">1</a>
    <a class="page-numbers">2</a>
    <a class="page-numbers">3</a>
    <a class="page-numbers">4</a>
    <a class="next page-numbers">&rarr;</a>
  </div>
</div>

<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want the opposite effect:

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.pagination-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination-wrapper {
  position: sticky;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 8px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.page-numbers {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  transition: 300ms ease;
  color: #595959;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.page-numbers:hover, .page-numbers.current {
  background-color: #86c023;
  color: #fff;
}

.page-numbers.prev:hover, .page-numbers.next:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #86c023;
}

.page-numbers {
  padding: 0 14px;
  display: none;
}

.page-numbers:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.page-numbers:nth-of-type(2)::after {
  content: "…";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
  top: 0;
  left: 45px;
}

.page-numbers:nth-child(-n + 3), .page-numbers:nth-last-child(-n + 3) {
  display: block;
}

.page-numbers:nth-last-child(-n + 4) {
  padding-right: 14px;
}

.page-numbers:nth-last-child(-n + 4)::after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>

<div class="pagination_extra"></div>

<div class="pagination-wrapper">
  <div class="pagination">
    <a class="prev page-numbers">&larr;</a>
    <a class="page-numbers">1</a>
    <a class="page-numbers">2</a>
    <a class="page-numbers">3</a>
    <a class="page-numbers">4</a>
    <a class="next page-numbers">&rarr;</a>
  </div>
</div>

<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Anyway, if you need to observe the position of the `.pagination_extra` element relative to the scroll position, you could use an [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to do that in a more performant and reliable way.